# Can I use multiple values in an api Get call?

Tags: api

For example, can I use a single api call to get all the contributions from contact a and contact b. My actual need is to get contributions from the contact and any related contacts, but I assume I need to do that as a previous step, which is done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, I just used the new API explorer in 4.6 and got a sample PHP call:

```
$result = civicrm_api3('Contribution', 'get', array( 
  'sequential' => 1,
  'contact_id' => array('IN' => array(58, 25)),
));
```